# SQL Server with returning JSON

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to get data from a controller with FOR JSON PATH as below :

```
DbConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr;
Object res ;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from myTable FOR JSON PATH";
cmd.Connection = DbConnection;

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

rdr.Read();
res = rdr[0];

DbConnection.Close ();
return Ok(res);
```

But the resulting object comes with back slashes before each property :

```
"[{\"codigo_do_registro\":1,\"descricao\":\"PLUVIOMETRO 01\",\"centro_de_custos\":\"DOM PEDRO\"
```

Instead of :

```
[{"codigo_do_registro":1,"descricao":"PLUVIOMETRO 01","centro_de_custos":"DOM PEDRO"
```

I think it's necessary other parameters to return data in the correct way but can't find it.

Any help please ?

Comment: I suppose those are escape characters? Otherwise the double quote would end the string right there. See [Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: Yes, they're escape sequences. Use `Regex.Unescape()` to eliminate them and return proper JSON string.

Comment: `FOR JSON PATH` says nothing about escaping the quotes around keys and values. It will only escape `"` as `\"` if that character occurs *inside* a key/value. Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\"` are escape sequence for double quotes, because `"` treated as special characters when written as `string`.

Here is an explanation taken from [How FOR JSON escapes special characters and control characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017):

> If the source data contains special characters, the FOR JSON clause
>   escapes them in the JSON output with `\`. This escaping occurs both in the names of properties and in
>   their values.

To remove escape sequences, just use [`Regex.Unescape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Unescape_System_String_) method when returning response:

```
DbConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr;
Object res;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "select * from myTable FOR JSON PATH";
   cmd.Connection = DbConnection;
   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   rdr.Read();
   res = rdr[0];
   DbConnection.Close ();
   return Ok(Regex.Unescape(res.ToString())); // unescape all escape sequences
}
```

Reference:

[SQL Server - Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Hi, changed the code as you suggested ( returning Ok(Regex.Unescape(res.ToString()));)  but the result is exactle the same as before

Comment: What about checking the `res` itself (put the result in browser's console)? Is that result passed to JS, and how you're seen that JSON string (from debugger or others)?